# NetSuite Restlet OAuth 2.0 Non-expiring Token (Now OA1.0)

Tags: oauth, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Quick question here, as I'm just dipping my toes into NetSuite Rest integrations for the first time.

I have a standard Oauth2.0 flow successfully authenticating with Access Token/Refresh token, but the access tokens expire after 3600 seconds.

[image]

The system I'm working with to talk to NetSuite only wants to do an Access Token as they don't have Refresh/Access flows yet.

Is there a way to increase the expiry of the access token from NetSuite to 24 hours or even longer?

Every day I can run a scheduled process from NetSuite to "subscribe" to the other system and provide them with the required Access token.

Comment: To a certain extent it depends on the application which is creating the tokens and how long can the timeline of access token be set but a good practice is to have the refresh tokens be used for renewing the access tokens instead of setting long-lived access tokens.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_160855594402.html

Comment: I dont think you could increase the lifetime of token, but, instead of OAuth2.0 based tokens if you used OAuth 1a based authentication, NetSuite will issue non-expiring token.

Comment: hmm thanks Prasun. I havent worked with OA1 as yet, I thought it had been deprecated

Comment: OAuth1.0 documentation is soooo.... confusing. doing my head in... is there an easy way to get the Token? I can't even figure out the Signature encoding...

Comment: @prasun would greatly appreciate your assitance with OAuth1.0a, in my separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256696/netsuite-oauth1-0a-obtaining-unauthorized-request-token-invalid-login-attemp